# Distinguishing between signed binary values

Tags: binary

Take the binary representation of 8 decimal: 0000 1000. Using two's complement, find the opposite by switching all the bits and adding one: 1111 1000. Now we have a binary representation for -8 decimal.

But how do we know whether to interpret this in decimal as -8 or 248?

Comment: 2's complement implies you're using signed values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When somebody writes down a binary number they usually specify whether it's signed or unsigned. If they don't specify anything you can assume that it's unsigned, i.e. 248 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

the sign bit, far left bit, most significant bit, is 1, that means it's a negative number.

and if you have 8 bits, you can only get -128 to 127   (those 256 different values). So the highest positive number is 01111111  You can't get above 127. So that's how you know.

note- that far left bit is still called a sign bit even though it's not the sign bit of sign and magnitude representation. It holds value besides the sign, but it does show the sign.
 [wikipedia twos complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)
"The most significant bit determines the sign of the number and is sometimes called the sign bit. Unlike in sign-and-magnitude representation, the sign bit also has the weight..".

On a slight tangent - I'd add the following, that as a shorthand to quickly do 2s complement, here's an example, if you have to put 0101 in 2s complement, go from the right hold the first 1. Then flick the rest. so  hold the 1 on the far right and flick the rest.  0101 becomes 1011.  Notice that is the same as the non-shortcut way of 0101 inverted to 1010 and adding 1 so 1011.  And when you have 1011  while you can subtract one and invert and get 0101.  And you can invert and add 1 and you get 0101.  You can also use the same same technique of holding the first 1 on the far right and flicking the rest, and you get back to 0101.  This works for any of them.  0110 in 2s complement,  hold the 10 on the far right, flick those to the left of it, you get 1010.

You could ask, how do you know it's in 2s complement, in the sense of, how do you know what number format the number is stored in. Whether it's 2s complement or 1s complement. Or sign magnitude or floating point. Well, you have to know 'cos you stored it! You can't store data and not remember what the data means!